# Geometry. Point in rectangle, but only angles from point to corners are known. Get triangle angles

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

![Sample of shapes and angles][1]

*Sorry, could not include picture of task dirrectly (need least 10 reputation to post images, have only 1 )".*

Picture of tasks: http://content31-foto.inbox.lv/albums/u/uwix/UwixWindV3/CAM03150.jpg

An irregular rectangle given, inside a point (not in center).
What we know:

- rectangle corner angles: A=90°, B=76° , C=104°, D=90°.
- rectangle shape size: AB=204mm, BC=154mm, CD=165.5mm, DA=148.5mm
- point x , which inside the rectangle
- point x "see" angles to rectangle corners: xAB=110° , xDA=79°, xCD=94°, xBC=77°

What to calculate:

- triangle forming angles: **Ab, Ba, Bc, Cb , Cd, Dc , Da , Ad**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** Sorry, this system is degenerated and has infinitely many solutions.
Additional equations, exploiting sine law, lead to non-analytic (numerical) solutions only. Example of Ba/Da relation:
`xA=AB*Sin(Ba)/Sin(xAB)=AD*Sin(Da)/Sin(xAD) => Sin(Ba)=Sin(Da)*AD*Sin(xAB)/(AB*Sin(xAD))`

**Update2:**
If we solve equation system below, expressing all unknowns through Ab angle, then
`Ba=70-Ab, Da=11+Ab`, we can substitute Ba and Da in the expression above, solve it numerically for Ab, then find all others angles.

**Update3:**
    Sin(Ba)=Sin(Da)*AD*Sin(xAB)/(AB*Sin(xAD))
    Sin(70-Ab) = Sin(11+Ab) * 148.5 * Sin(110) / (204 * Sin(79)) = 0.6968 * Sin(11+Ab)

I made the plots of Sin(70-Ab) and 0.6968 * Sin(11+Ab) in range 0..90 and found they intersect approximately at 38.18 degrees (Ab = 38.18).
(I didn't search numerical solution for `Sin(70-Ab) - 0.6968 * Sin(11+Ab) = 0`)

I denote central angles as xAB, xBC, xCD, xDA, and small angles near corners as Ab, Ad, Ba, Bc, Cb, Cd, Dc, Da. Then we have 8 linear equations and 8 unknowns:

```
Ab + Ad = A (90)
Ba + Bc = B
Cb + Cd = C
Dc + Da = D
Ab + Ba = 180 - xAB
Bc + Cb = 180 - xBC
Cd + Dc = 180 - xCD
Da + Ad = 180 - xDA
```

We can solve this system or in symbolic way, getting common solution, or using the numbers given.
Then it is possible to find x* segment lengths through sine law:

```
xA / Sin(Ba) = AB / Sin(xAB)
```

Comment: This final sine equation doesnot help, only what you get is kinda proportion not the value of length xA or angle Ba.

Comment: final equation doesn't help, but another relation could help (added)

Comment: The upper given "Example Ba/Da relation ... " involves again in both sides unknown values. If i could get ANY of unknown angles all puzle is immediately solved. Now seems kinda magic loop.

Comment: sorry, I am stupid, but not understood where You got the numeric values ` Ba=70-Ab, Da=11+Ab ` ? Have no such angles in lists.

Comment: I calculate them from eq. system. 1st eq: Ad = 90 - Ab   Last eq: Da = 180 - 79 - (90 - Ab)=11 + Ab and so on...

Comment: Have created excel table with those formula - making variable Ab 0..90 degree, output both sides .
`Sin(70-Ab) ?== SIN(11°-Ab) * 148.5mm * SIN(110°) / (204mm * SIN(79°))`

Have comparator between rezults - rounding down 2 chars after coma. Nobody matched. Expected that it should Ab angle be 38 degree. 

Whats wrong in that aproach?

Comment: Have fixed sign (11+Ab) in formula: `Sin(70-Ab) ?== SIN(11°+Ab) * 148.5mm * SIN(110°) / (204mm * SIN(79°))`

When rounding to 1 char after koma `=IF(ROUNDDOWN(D3;1)=ROUNDDOWN(F3;1);"TRUE";"-")`- have got 3 matches: 4°, 26°, 48° - noone is close to 38° -the correct answer.

Comment: Note plus sign - Sin(11 + Ab). And yes, Ab is about 38.18 degrees - this is intersection point of plot Sin(DegToRad(70 - x)) and plot 0.6968 * Sin(DegToRad(x + 11))

Comment: Could you please extract this as variable formula as solution update, not understood how you get two lines to intersect ? Especially how you get value (0.6968). Apreciate if you give intersection formula applying variables here.. so we go out 38.18°